# DUDAS PRINTF y mejora de código

Tags: c++, printf

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int bomba = 10000;


main ()
{
    int sedan = 60, convertible = 60; 
    int todoterreno = 120, furgoneta = 120; 
    int transporte= 200;
    int l;
    
    printf ("\n__________________BIENVENIDO A LA GASOLINERA DE EDUARDO :)___________________\n");
    printf ("\n\t\t###########MENU DE OPCIONES###########");
    printf ("\n\n---Llenar SEDAN con (60 LT)--------------------PRESIONE 1 ° Solo usar numeros °" "\n------LLenar TODOTERRENO con (120 LT)----------PRECIONE 2\n"  "----Llenar TRANSPORTE PUBLICO con (200 LT)---- PRECIONE 3" "\n----Llenar FURGONETA con (120 LT)--------------PRESIONE 4" );
    printf ("\n________________________________________________________________________________");
    
    do{
        cout<< "\n\n\nQue modelo deseas llenar???:";
        scanf("%d", &l);
        
        if(bomba <=5000){
            puts("\n°°°°°°°°°La bomba de gasolina esta a media capacidad!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        if(bomba <= 2000){
            puts("UUPPS, ya queda muy poca gasolina...Tienes que REABASTECER \nLa gasolinera de eduardo quedo en quiebra EL PROGRAMA SE VA A CERRAR \nVuelva pronto :)");
            exit(-1);
        }
        
        switch (l)
        {
            case 1: 
            
                bomba-=sedan;//bomba=bomba-sedan;
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°° SE LLENO TU SEDAN CON 60 LITROS °°°°°°°°°°");
                printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
                printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");                   
                break;
            
            case 2:
            
                bomba-=todoterreno;//bomba=bomba-todoterreno;
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°  SE LLENO TU TODOTERRENO CON 120 LITROS °°°°°°°");
                printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
                printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");                   
                break;
            
            case 3:
                bomba-=transporte;
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°° SE LLENO TU TRANSPORTE CON 200 LITROS °°°°°°°°°°");
                printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
                printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");                   
                break;
                
            case 4:
            
                bomba-=furgoneta;//bomba=bomba-furgoneta;
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°  SE LLENO TU FURGONETA CON 120 LITROS °°°°°°°°°");
                printf("\n     °                                                        °");   
                printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d         °", bomba);
                printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n");    
            
            default:
            puts("\n No te puedo atender con ese vocabulario...");
            break;
        }
    }while(l!=10000000);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Termine de hacer este programa, funciona para lo que quiero pero en tema de diseño le falta algo
¿Cómo hago para que los prinft que  están encima del  DO se queden estáticos en la parte de arriba?,
cuando se elije una opción los resultados van bajando y se pierde el menú de vista.  Si meto las impresiones en el do queda feo...

Se que el menú se puede  hacer mucho mejor pero esto es lo que tengo ahora, estoy aprendiendo

No obstante, ¿Cómo lo hubieran hecho ustedes? como es un ejerció simple y no le tengo que preguntar al usuario ningún dato para que resuelva un problema, se me ocurrió solo hacer impresiones  en pantalla de datos ya programados

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es limpiar la pantalla y reescribir la parte de arriba (header) cada vez que hay un cambio. En vez de escribir el header y luego entrar al ciclo, puedes es entrar al cliclo, limpiar pantalla y escribir el header en cada ciclo, eso hace que parezca "estático"

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer para ahorrarte unos cuantos `printf()` es crear funciones que contengan los mensajes.
Para el menu principal:

```
void menu() {
    printf("\n__________________BIENVENIDO A LA GASOLINERA DE EDUARDO :)___________________\n");
    printf("\n\t\t###########MENU DE OPCIONES###########");
    printf("\n\n---Llenar SEDAN con (60 LT)--------------------PRESIONE 1 ° Solo usar numeros °" "\n------LLenar TODOTERRENO con (120 LT)----------PRECIONE 2\n"  "----Llenar TRANSPORTE PUBLICO con (200 LT)---- PRECIONE 3" "\n----Llenar FURGONETA con (120 LT)--------------PRESIONE 4" );
    printf("\n________________________________________________________________________________");
}
```

Y para los mensajes de llenado:

```
void mensaje(const char *marca, int bomba){
    cout << "\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°° SE LLENO TU " << marca << " CON 60 LITROS °°°°°°°°°°";
    printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
    printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");
```

}

Así aunque coloques el menu dentro de los DO no se verá tan mal.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, como acoplo void menú correctamente al codigo? en que parte,afuera del main?

Comment: Debes declararlos antes del main, luego simplemente los llamas en la parte que los quieres ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta uno de los comentarios que ya te hicieron, tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
#include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int bomba = 10000;
    
    void menu();
    main ()
    {
        int sedan = 60, convertible = 60; 
        int todoterreno = 120, furgoneta = 120; 
        int transporte= 200;
        int l;
               
        do{
            menu();
            cout<< "\n\n\nQue modelo deseas llenar???:";
            scanf("%d", &l);
            
            if(bomba <=5000){
                puts("\n°°°°°°°°°La bomba de gasolina esta a media capacidad!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
            if(bomba <= 2000){
                puts("UUPPS, ya queda muy poca gasolina...Tienes que REABASTECER \nLa gasolinera de eduardo quedo en quiebra EL PROGRAMA SE VA A CERRAR \nVuelva pronto :)");
                exit(-1);
            }
            
            switch (l)
            {
                case 1: 
                
                    bomba-=sedan;//bomba=bomba-sedan;
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°° SE LLENO TU SEDAN CON 60 LITROS °°°°°°°°°°");
                    printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
                    printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");                   
                    break;
                
                case 2:
                
                    bomba-=todoterreno;//bomba=bomba-todoterreno;
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°  SE LLENO TU TODOTERRENO CON 120 LITROS °°°°°°°");
                    printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
                    printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");                   
                    break;
                
                case 3:
                    bomba-=transporte;
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°° SE LLENO TU TRANSPORTE CON 200 LITROS °°°°°°°°°°");
                    printf("\n     °                                                         °");   
                    printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d          °", bomba);
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°");                   
                    break;
                    
                case 4:
                
                    bomba-=furgoneta;//bomba=bomba-furgoneta;
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°  SE LLENO TU FURGONETA CON 120 LITROS °°°°°°°°°");
                    printf("\n     °                                                        °");   
                    printf("\n     °             LITROS DE GASOLINA RESTANTES: %d         °", bomba);
                    printf("\n     °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n");    
                
                default:
                puts("\n No te puedo atender con ese vocabulario...");
                break;
            }
            sleep(2);//Con esto te esperas a que se muestre el resultado del switch y vuelva a hacerse el while
        }while(l!=10000000);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    void menu(){
            system("clear");//Se limpia la consola para hacer el efecto de que esta siempre el menu
            printf ("\n__________________BIENVENIDO A LA GASOLINERA DE EDUARDO :)___________________\n");
            printf ("\n\t\t###########MENU DE OPCIONES###########");
            printf ("\n\n---Llenar SEDAN con (60 LT)--------------------PRESIONE 1 ° Solo usar numeros °" "\n------LLenar TODOTERRENO con (120 LT)----------PRECIONE 2\n"  "----Llenar TRANSPORTE PUBLICO con (200 LT)---- PRECIONE 3" "\n----Llenar FURGONETA con (120 LT)--------------PRESIONE 4" );
            printf ("\n________________________________________________________________________________");
    }
```

Comment: HAAA ok ok,se declara el void antes de todo, luego llamas  el void en el lugar que deseas y a lo ultimo después del main indicas que debe imprimir el void, perfecto muchas gracias. Pero¿ por que se indica que lleva el void a lo ultimo y no mas arriba?. Otra cosa,cuando compila el "system clear" no se reconoce como comando externo o interno

Comment: En donde utilizas el compilado? Ten en cuenta que system te va a ejecutar comandos de tu sistema, y en caso de Windows no existe clear. Prueba a cambiarlo por cls

Comment: En donde utilizas el compilado? Ten en cuenta que system te va a ejecutar comandos de tu sistema, y en caso de Windows no existe clear. Prueba a cambiarlo por cls

Comment: Quedo justo como me lo imaginaba, muchas gracias, si funciono cls

Comment: Lo declaro arriba mas por buenas practicas, pero sin problema lo puedes declarar arriba. Y lo del comando ya te lo respondieron , hahaha.